# Using double in Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, double

I'm very new to iOS and swift 2 and I am making an app which would require a double value for the attribute of an entity in core data. There are many tutorials with strings as attributes but no double. Can you please help me by showing an example of  how double attribute can be created using core data .I want to store the value in a table view controller. Thanks in advance

Comment: `Double` is one of the supported Core Data attribute types. Where is the problem? All numeric types are bridged to `NSNumber` anyway.

Comment: I'm having trouble when I'm trying to get value from a text field and saving it to the entity because in my model it says its of type double and in my entity I'm getting the value from a text field which is a string and when I try to store it in my entity.attribute it says cannot assign string to type double. I tried typecasting it as double(textfield.text) but i'm still getting errors. any help will be appreciated

Comment: This is very basic stuff. Please read the chapter [The Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html) in the Language Guide to get use to type conversion and optionals.