# How to save UIStepper to CoreData (swift 3)

Tags: core-data, swift3, uistepper

I use UIStepper in a tapleviewcell but I don't know how to save stepper value in my CoreData?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: StepperTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! StepperTableViewCell

    //stepper is your UIStepper reference from StepperTableViewCell
    cell.stepper.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.stepper.addTarget(self, action: #selector(stepperAction(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)

    return cell
}
func stepperAction(sender: UIStepper)  {
    print("Stepper \(sender.tag) clicked. Its value \(sender.value)")
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do? Just save the sender.value? Do you really need core-data? Maybe UserDefaults will be great, too? For core-data have a look here https://www.raywenderlich.com/145809/getting-started-core-data-tutorial or here https://learnappdevelopment.com/ios-app-development-free/how-to-use-core-data-in-ios-10-swift-3/ or here https://medium.com/ios-geek-community/beginners-guide-to-core-data-in-swift-3-85292ef4edd#.gnbnvyows

Comment: I use CoreData in my project and the stepper is a part of it. I know how to save text from UITextfield to CoreData but I don't know how to save IUStepper value in the CoreData

Comment: Anyhow I don't understand the problem. sender.value is a double or a number, isn't it? Core Data supports double. Save it in the same way like the string. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37958530/using-double-in-core-data

Comment: My UIStepper in a tableviewcell and I don't know how can I save the stepper who just tapped, sorry about my language.

Answer (score 1):

1.You create a variable in your *StepperTableViewCell* like this

```
var callBackStepper:((_ value:Double)->())?
```

2.You create an IBACTION in your *StepperTableViewCell* (don't forget make an reference to your UI)
That could have a look like this:

```
@IBAction func stepperTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
   callBackStepper?(sender.value)
}
```

3. In your UIViewController where the tableView you set the callback

   ```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell: StepperTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! StepperTableViewCell

   cell.callBackStepper = { value in
      print("every time called when you use UIStepper \(value)")
    }
   return cell
   }
   ```

It's untested, but it should work, please give a feedback

Comment: I don't test it yet but how to save the stepper value which is for every cell in CoreData?

Comment: I thought u know how to save the value persistently when you have the value? You always get the value in the callback. To save it persistently have a look stackoverflow.com/questions/37958530/using-double-in-core-da‌​ta
Please test code first!

Comment: I tested it, now I have the value but I have value in every cell because I have tableview in my project, so how can I update CoreData with every new stepper value which is in every cell.

Comment: can you share your project with github or as zip?

Comment: It's complicated to understand:( but I have a tableview and in every cell I have stepper, now I can get the stepper value but I don't know how to update/edit the old value in the CoreData.

Comment: Please use google. The web has a lot of entries about the topic. For example that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26345189/how-do-you-update-a-coredata-entry-that-has-already-been-saved-in-swift You have the value, update it and then make a tableView.reloadData() where the new values are used.

Comment: I did, but it's not working :( can you give me an example which can be used with swift 3 to update/edit stepper value in CoreData? Thank you a lot sir:)